# Prove $c^{-1}(|x_1|^a+\dots+|x_n|^a)\leq |x|^a\leq c(|x_1|^a+\dots+|x_n|^a)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $||x||_2$ is the Euclidean norm of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If $a>0$, Prove $\exists$ $c>0$ depending on $n$ and $a$ s.t. $$c^{-1}(|x_1|^a+\dots+|x_n|^a)\leq ||x||_2^a\leq c(|x_1|^a+\dots+|x_n|^a)$$

Comment: Bonus question: Find an explicit form for $c(a,n)$ :)

Comment: are $x_i$ the coordinates? If they are I would use different symbols for absolute value and norm (even though absolute value is a norm in $\mathbb R$, it still stems confusion).

Comment: @GPerez Yes.I think

Comment: please, make an attempt. take $n=2$ or/and $a=1$ as a toy example and have a go. something like arithmetic-quadratic mean inequality is useful here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First divide the inequality by the maximum element $x_j$'s size.

Now note that (why?): $$1<\frac{||x||_2^a}{|x_j|^a} < n^{a/2}$$
Can you prove $c=n^{a/2-1}$ is a sufficient choice?